# How to import _ssl in python 2.7.6?

Tags: python, ssl, https, httpserver

My http server is based on BaseHTTPServer with Python 2.7.6. Now I want it to support ssl transportation, so called https.

I have installed pyOpenSSL and recompiled python source code with ssl support. And it does work when I try `import ssl` in my python interpreter, but it doesn't work when I run the code on my server. The error log is like this:

> import _ssl # if we can't import it, let the error propagate

It looks quite strange, doesn't it? My operating system is Debian Linux distribution. I have tried all kinds of ways which I can find on the Internet for days, anyone can help me get out of this trouble?

---

I tried to "import _ssl" in server code directly, but it reminds me this:

```
>>>callstack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script/main.py", line 85, in process
    net_flag = net_api_process()
  File "./script/core/netbase/interface.py", line 96, in net_api_process
    flag1 = network.instance().process()
  File "./script/core/netbase/network.py", line 271, in process
    if network.process(max_events):
  File "./script/core/netbase/network.py", line 75, in on_incomin_stream
    self.on_package(buf)
  File "./script/core/netbase/network.py", line 78, in on_package
    self.f_on_package(self, buf)
  File "./script/client/behavior.py", line 68, in on_package
    handler.OnPackage(pack, cmd, conn.m_uid, conn)
  File "./script/client/handler.py", line 288, in OnPackage
    func(uid, conn, pack)
  File "./script/logic/user_info/modify.py", line 365, in OnModBaseInfo
    ModBaseInfo(uid, conn, seq, json_str)
  File "./script/logic/user_info/modify.py", line 385, in ModBaseInfo
    modify_pub.Start()
  File "./script/logic/user_info/modify.py", line 253, in Start
    import _ssl
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Comment: Is that the complete log message? It looks very terse. Is there any more (e.g., the full traceback)?

Comment: Also, `import ssl` (what you tested manually), and `import _ssl` (on the server), are two different things: the first just points to a pure Python module, the second points to a compiled binary. It looks like the latter can't be found, so Python SSL support didn't now get properly installed.

Comment: the full traceback: File "./script/http/httpServer.py", line 23, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 2298, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 2273, in _initialize_openssl_threads
ImportError: No module named _ssl

Comment: I can "import _ssl" in python interpreter successfully, but not in server code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the problem finally!
The _ssl module is a built-in module for python, but it requires openssl installed on your system.

Change to root user first!
1.Install openssl and libssl-dev.
If on debian OS

```
apt-get install openssl
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

2.Recompile python

```
cd Python2.7.6
./configure
make && make install
```

But actually, I fix the problem in this way!
1.Install openssl
I download a package from the Internet, which is openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz

```
tar zxvf openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2d
./config -fPIC   //configuration：create path independent libssl.a
make && make install
```

2.Recompile python2.7, and make it support ssl module

```
tar xvf Python-2.7.6.tar
cd Python-2.7.6
vim Modules/Setup.dist
```

find the following line and uncomment it.(use /ssl+Enter to quickly locate these lines in vim)

```
# Socket module helper for socket(2)
_socket socketmodule.c timemodule.c

# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
        -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
        -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

and then config and make, make install

```
./configure --enable-shared //--enable-shared option means to generate dynamic library libpython2.7.so.1.0
make && make install
```

Our project depends on libpython2.7.so.1.0. Now I can "import ssl" or "import _ssl" successfully in my python script or python interpreter with the new libpython2.7.so.1.0.