# CQL Login Error in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am able to start Cassandra 3 without any issue, but the `cqlsh` script is not starting. I am using CentOS 6 and Python installed is 2.7. Here is the error message:

```
[hadoop@hadoop1 bin]$ cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py", line 168, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling, cqlshhandling
  File "/opt/cassandra/bin/../pylib/cqlshlib/sslhandling.py", line 20, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Please help.

regards
Sajith

Answer (score 1):

The error which you have received is related to missing python package.
Check the below solved question solves your CQL error:

[How to import _ssl in python 2.7.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856389/how-to-import-ssl-in-python-2-7-6)